# Should you always use regularization tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I was wondering whether or not I need to always use regularization with tensorflow.

```
def regularize(cost, theta, beta):
    return beta * tf.nn.l2_loss(theta)
```

I know it's used for avoiding overfitting, but my question is whether it should always be used. I used it for the Titanic Competition on Kaggle, and it didn't improve my score anymore that without regularization. Therefore, should I make it a habit to always regularize my cost function or only to do it in specific circumstances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, there is no "ground truth" as to how you should approach a specific problem. The use of a loss function (including a regularizer) is a vast field and has been asked many times, including on Stackoverflow.

EDIT: Also consider looking at answers over at the [DataScience stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13031/should-i-use-regularization-every-time), which might be better suited for these kinds of questions.

In your case, regularization - specifically a L2 regularizer - can be used to keep weights in a network small, or in other words penalize outliers more heavily, since they effectively can cost you a lot in terms of generalization.

Now, if we take for example the task of [image colorization](https://blog.floydhub.com/colorizing-b-w-photos-with-neural-networks/), a regularizer might exactly do opposite of what we want! More specifically, any good colorization has a strong and clear contrast, and saturated color values. 
If, on the other hand, such strong color values are repressed by a regularized loss function, most of your resulting images will look very dark, since no strong colors are effectively allowed.
Thus, it would be better to *not* use a regularizer.

Certainly there are more examples, and a regularizer can still make sense in some cases. I would judge not only based on performance, but also think about what it [does mathematically](https://towardsdatascience.com/l1-and-l2-regularization-methods-ce25e7fc831c), to judge whether it makes sense in your example.
Oftentimes, you would investigate your data set in terms of outliers, variance, etc. to find out whether it might be a good idea to effectively utilize all samples (no regularization), or penalize the few heavy outliers you have.